# Can von Neumann entropy be used to characterize atomic and nuclear processes as spontaneous?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Gibbs free energy (involving entropy) can be used to characterize thermodynamic and chemical processes as spontaneous ($delta G < 0$). Can the same be done for atomic and nuclear processes by means of von Neumann entropy?

Comment: Interesting question. Probably partially overlaps (or is closely related) with: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/367557/is-the-von-neumann-entropy-related-to-heat-transfer?rq=1